# Placing JavaScript content in Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I'm having trouble placing JavaScript inside of my Popover. I want to place a Graph, from Chart.js, inside of the Popover when clicked. For the sake of the example lets use the example graph from their documentation http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

So far I have my Popover -

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
        data-toggle="popover" 
        title="Good vs. Evil Winrate" 
        data-placement="bottom" 
        data-content="Graph coming soon!">
    Who's Winning?
</button>
```

And the jQuery to initialize it -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

I just don't understand how to place the graph inside of the Popover, everything I've tried breaks it to a point of the Popover not opening at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the [popover options in JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) directly, and you can also listen to events.

The important option here is `html: true` which enables placing HTML within the popover content, otherwise shown as a string.

The [`content` option documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) states:

> Default content value if `data-content` attribute isn't present.

Then, listening to the `shown.bs.popover` event, we get the previously placed `<canvas>` with jQuery and pass it as the context for a new Chart.js instance.

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  html: true,
  content: '<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>',
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {

  new Chart($('#myChart'), {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
      }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Good vs. Evil Winrate" data-placement="bottom">Who's Winning?</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That works. My issue was trying to mix the JS and jQuery together instead of just initializing with JS as well.

Comment: Note to anyone else in the future -- if you have `data-content=` set it will override the JavaScript, as I just learned.

Comment: @BrettJ nice catch!

Comment: hi Emile, i try to adopt yor snippet im my script. I have some question. 1) why you don't loa load popper.js? 2 ) whre you render graph if fault context. When i try this come up error: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Comment: @sundsx notice that this is an old thread which uses [Bootstrap 3.3.7](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/). [Popper is used in Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js). I don't understand your second question, though, if you're not using the same versions as my answer, you might really well encounter problems!

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron for replying. The second question is related to the context that chart.js requires to render the chart. The context seems to be missing from your code. However, I managed to get the result via javascript appendChild (context)! Thank a lot

Comment: @sundsx I am getting the exact same error, can you elaborate a bit? Where do you add the appendchild ?